# Have the same WebAssembly instance in two Web Workers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, go, webpack, webassembly

I use a wasm file compiled from golang (version 1.3.5), I have certain functions which use goroutines, however they are not supported, and when I call them, they run in the current thread and they slow down my worker considerably.

So I would like to create a worker inside my current worker and have it call the function in question, so that it is multi-threaded.

I am using webpack worker-loader to make my current web worker.

Is it possible to share a WebAssembly instance between two web workers?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is normally good practice to include example code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO's guidelines on how to answer a good question include showing a code example of what you have tried so far; AKA a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This A) shows that you've put effort into trying to solve the problem yourself, B) makes your question more specific, C) you're more likely to solve the question yourself, and overall it makes it more likely you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently share WebAssembly instances between workers.   You can however instantiate the same module on both workers and shared the memory via a SharedArrayBuffer.  Indeed this is how emscripten implements pthreads.

This will only work on browsers that enable SharedArrayBuffers and implement the WebAssembly threads proposal.